# Why does this array give me trouble?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

If I write this:

```
int array[] = {2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5};
for (int i : array) {

}
```

..it's OK, but if I write this:

```
int array[] = {2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5};
int i = 0;
for (i : array) {

}
```

It gives me issues. My teacher says that he wants us always to initialize at the top, how doesn't like that we put the `int` inside of the `for`...

Is there other ways to write it?

Comment: int i and int i = 0 isn't the same.

Comment: Add language tags, Like C, C++, or JAVA something like that.

Comment: Please describe the issues you're talking about.

Comment: What do you mean, *"It gives me issues"*?

Comment: Programming idiom: Declare types in a foreach loop `(final Type variable : iterable)`.

Comment: Find another teacher, both syntaxes are perfectly OK and the first is better if you dont want to reuse the variable later.

Comment: @MightyPork The "issue" here is ... that the second one simply does not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24013205/3182664

Comment: see my answer at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011816/scope-of-local-variable-in-enhanced-for-loop)

Comment: @Marco13 I see, that's weird. But actually, I can't imagien ever doing it the second way, so I never came across this peculiarity.

Comment: BTW, in other languages (like JavaScript's for .. in ) what you wanted to do is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're using is a special case of a for loop, sometimes called a "for-in" loop. Your teacher probably wants a more traditional C style for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // you need to say array[i] to access elements here
}
```

The difference is that a for-in loop doesn't use a counter (loop induction variable), it uses an uninitialised value `i` and binds that name to each element of the array as you iterate.

Answer (score 1):

The [for each loop](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html) in Java expects a *type* and you haven't provided one. You've only given it the variable `i`.

```
for (type var : arr) {
    // body-of-loop
}
```

Leaving out the type is a syntax error. If your instructor insists that you declare `i` before the loop, you'll have to use a regular [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // body-of-loop
}
```

(Although I disagree that this is good style.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through all elements of an array, these are the two ways :

When you only need the element :

```
for (int element : array) {
    ...
}
```

When you also need the index (`i`) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int element = array[i];
    ...
}
```

For the second loop, if your teacher wants you to declare everything at the top, you can do this :

```
int element;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    element = array[i];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're effectively changing it from:

```
int array[] = {2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5};
for (int i : array) {

}
```

to

```
int array[] = {2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5};
for (int i = 0: array) {

}
```

which doesn't really make sense if you try to read it. Ask, "what is it trying to do?" - in the first case, you're telling it take all of the integers in the array. Yet in the second, you're trying to somehow specify where to start, but to the code it doesn't make sense: how can you go from 0 to an array?

Another way to write it would be:

```
int array[] = {2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 5};
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   int j = array[i]; // takes the value of the array at index i
}
```

This starts at index 0, and iterates through index #5, increasing the index by 1 each time. Array indices in java begin with 0 and end with 1 less than the length, so `i` will go from 0 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

When using the for each java construct, which you are, it is considered perfectly acceptable (and necessary) to declare the `int` as part of the for loop, as in your first code block.

Your teacher is likely to be worried about not having a defined value for your variable but in this case it is acceptable since the integer `i` will always be bound to a value of the array or collection given to it after the colon.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a foreach statement (in Java is called "[enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)") you have to declare the type of the variabile inside the statement, or it won't compile. If you want to initialize at the top, you cannot use the foreach, but a simple for loop like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < array.length; i++) {

}
```

or

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

}
```